# Get numbers from .dat file with C#

Tags: c#, file

I want to read Coordinate Values from .dat file. The problem is I can't split characters
to identify coordinates.

[example http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/3733791211.png](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/3733791211.png)

Comment: Shouldn't be to hard to parse that file by hand. Have a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First version**

in the first version i just use .Replace(".", ",") method to replace the dot by the comma

```
public Double[] GridValues(int fromline) 
{
    Double[] values = new Double[7];
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    {
        string input = ReadLine(fromline).Substring(8 * i, 8).Replace(".", ",");
        values[i-1] = double.Parse(input);
    }

    return values;
}
```

**Second version**

In the seconde vesion i pass an IFormatProvider to the Parse() method that defines . as the

decimal separator

```
public Double[] GridValues(int fromline) 
{
    Double[] values = new Double[7];
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    {
        string input = ReadLine(fromline).Substring(8 * i, 8);
        values[i-1] = double.Parse(input,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your image appears to be of a fixed-width file, so once you know the offsets of each column you can extract them with `String.Substring(offset,length)`.

Comment: pleaze you can tell me how can i parse number like "0-.1234" or ".234"

Comment: Try `Decimal value = Decimal.Parse(string)`

Comment: What exception or results are you getting?

Comment: Make sure you're passing a string in the format of a decimal number (x.xxx or -x.xxx). I don't know of anything that could parse "0-.1234" because I don't know what kind of number that is. If it fails on ".234" you may need to test for a leading period and append a "0" to it before trying to parse.